# Make some text bold inside StaticLayout in android

Tags: android, staticlayout

Is there any way to make some text bold of a static layout? I am trying to print one government document so that I have used StaticLayout using following code to set text on `Canvas`.

```
TextPaint mTextPaint=new TextPaint();
mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/times.ttf"));

    StaticLayout mTextLayout;
    canvas.save();

mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(getText(), mTextPaint, pageInfo.getPageWidth()/2-otherPadding*3, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 1.0f, true);
translate(textX, textY);
draw(canvas);
....
```

Where `getText()` method returns the String which I want to print as given below.

```
String getText()
{
     return "Name and complete address of Genetic Clinic/Ultrasound Clinic/Imaging centre : "+hospital.getName();
}
```

So Here I want to make hospital name bold only.

Comment: Did you manage to make some text bold within a static layout? I'd appreciate any help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make text bold in either ways:

When you call `setTypeface()` you can also pass second parameter:
`mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/times.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD);`

OR in your xml

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Comment: I don't want to make all text bold , instead I only want to make **hospital name** bold only.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
<string name="hospital message">Name and complete address of Genetic Clinic/Ultrasound Clinic/Imaging centre : <b> %1$s </b></string>
```

and then:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.hospital_message), hospital.getName());
```

Comment: In my question, I am passing the string from java, not from the resource file.